# Flash + Javascript + HTTPS (SSL)

Tags: javascript, flash, ssl, https

I want to support purchasing items via a flash SWF.

Does flash support posting to HTTPs?
(given that the object container uses the https versions of the player)

If the above is a problem (posting HTTPs via flash) can I communicate javascript<->flash inside an HTTPs html and post via javascript?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no different than anything else under HTTPS. Just make sure it's hosted on the same HTTPS server as anything else, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I was worried that because its HTTPs + ActiveX there would be some restraints as to what an ActiveX can do.