# Client Certificate SSL in Flash

Tags: flash, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to get a flash object to use the client SSL certificate that the browser is using in a session for authentication?

This is a general question, however in my specific case I am trying to use the Uploadify jQuery plugin (http://www.uploadify.com/).

Related: [Flash + Javascript + HTTPS (SSL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724929/flash-javascript-https-ssl)